# multiple fields with jQuery Wan Spinner Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, multiple-instances

I would like to create a table with input fields using this pluggin(or similar):

[Number Picker pluggin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Minimal-Number-Picker-Plugin-For-jQuery-Wan-Spinner.html)

In the demo if I simply add:

```
<div class="wan-spinner wan-spinner-4">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="minus">-</a>
    <input type="text" value="1">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus">+</a>
  </div>
```

the newly added item is not working. So I'm adding new line:

```
$(".wan-spinner-4").WanSpinner({inputWidth: 100}).css("border-color", "#C0392B");
```

And everything is working for the new item.

So if there is a table with 100 rows - should I generate 100 rows:

```
$(".wan-spinner-4").WanSpinner({inputWidth: 100}).css("border-color", "#C0392B");
```

or there is a generic solution for this.

Comment: aren't you using any loop for generating the 100 rows? or some plugin maybe?

Comment: yes I'm using a loop which is generating the values. In pseudo code: foreach person: <input ... >

Comment: so you just need a single line code. just place it right after the loop and it should apply to all the rows

Comment: yes I can do it like this: foreach person :  <div class="wan-spinner wan-spinner-4">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="minus">-</a>
    <input type="text" value="1">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus">+</a>
  </div> $(".wan-spinner-4").WanSpinner({inputWidth: 100}).css("border-color", "#C0392B");. Isn't it to heavy for 1000 rows and is there a way to do it with variable and single line?

Comment: nop you should NOT do it inside your loop, but right AFTER the loop, just a single line. Plus, you CAN'T place javascript in the HTML code..

Comment: is that `foreach` instruction PHP or javascript?

Comment: Actually is groovy code - similar to PHP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112146/discussion-between-vanko-and-pumpkinzzz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since loop is server side you just need to wait document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(".wan-spinner-4").WanSpinner({inputWidth: 100}).css("border-color", "#C0392B"); 
})
```